# Null error when using .createInvite method in v13 API

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using this basic code to have a bot generate an invite link to a server - where guild ID is the string of my guild ID:

```
const Guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId);
            
const invite = await Guild.systemChannel.createInvite({
    maxAge: 14,
    maxUses: 10,
    unique: true
});
```

Upon doing this, I receive the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createInvite')`

I wonder if anyone could possibly point out if I used this method incorrectly?

Just for some extra information, my guild object is returned fine as below:

```
<ref *2> Guild {
  id: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  name: 'NAMEHERE',
  icon: 'a_479390a16bfef56aee3c39330d4d2e3e',
  features: [
    'MEMBER_PROFILES',
    'ROLE_ICONS',
    'PRIVATE_THREADS',
    'THREE_DAY_THREAD_ARCHIVE',
    'SEVEN_DAY_THREAD_ARCHIVE',
    'INVITE_SPLASH',
    'BANNER',
    'ANIMATED_ICON'
  ],
  commands: <ref *1> GuildApplicationCommandManager {
    permissions: ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager {
      manager: [Circular *1],
      guild: [Circular *2],
      guildId: 'CENSORED',
      commandId: null
    },
    guild: [Circular *2]
  },
  members: GuildMemberManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  channels: GuildChannelManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  bans: GuildBanManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  roles: RoleManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  presences: PresenceManager {},
  voiceStates: VoiceStateManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  stageInstances: StageInstanceManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  invites: GuildInviteManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  deleted: false,
  available: true,
  shardId: 0,
  splash: '53c57d1053959d572635640ef34aecce',
  banner: null,
  description: null,
  verificationLevel: 'MEDIUM',
  vanityURLCode: null,
  nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
  discoverySplash: null,
  memberCount: 459,
  large: true,
  applicationId: null,
  afkTimeout: 300,
  afkChannelId: null,
  systemChannelId: null,
  premiumTier: 'TIER_2',
  premiumSubscriptionCount: 9,
  explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
  mfaLevel: 'NONE',
  joinedTimestamp: 1634610823632,
  defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
  systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  maximumMembers: 250000,
  maximumPresences: null,
  approximateMemberCount: null,
  approximatePresenceCount: null,
  vanityURLUses: null,
  rulesChannelId: null,
  publicUpdatesChannelId: null,
  preferredLocale: 'en-US',
  ownerId: 'CENSORED',
  emojis: GuildEmojiManager { guild: [Circular *2] },
  stickers: GuildStickerManager { guild: [Circular *2] }
}
```

Comment: `Guild.systemChannel` is returning null, make sure `Guild` returns what you're expecting and check `.systemChannel`

Comment: Yep and I see this - but Guild is returning the guild object correctly but not with a systemChannel string in the object. Any idea why? This function works on some of my servers and not on others and I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why

Comment: Just updated my post with the guild object we are mentioning - I'm following the discord v13 api as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

As per the [discord.js docs for `Guild#systemChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel), that property can be null, which means not every Guild has a `systemChannel`. You might want to check if it is null before the creating the invite, so you can choose another channel in case it is.